# How to extract specific range within excel worksheets and consolidate

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate a report task in excel, I need to consolidate all workbooks in a folder into one worksheet, I followed the guide provided by danwagner here : https://danwagner.co/how-to-combine-multiple-excel-workbooks-into-one-worksheet-with-vba/

It works very well however due to the unstructured nature of the data I am not getting the desired results.

Basically I would like the excel macro to only pick up a specific range of values, I am defining the upper row and number of columns but don't know how to have excel strictly copy out/extract a table within each worksheet(each workbook has the same starting row and number of columns for the table however the bottom row of the table vary).

The table I need to grab from each workbook looks something like this, there is only one worksheet in each workbook to consolidate together:[image: A sample excel worksheet]

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, btw I believe the edits need to be done on these lines of the macro from the guide but I keep running into errors:

```
        lngSrcLastCol = LastOccupiedColNum(wksSrc)
        With wksSrc
            Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngSrcLastRow, _
                                                     lngSrcLastCol))
        End With
```

Comment: Is the first cell in each worksheet the same? If so, you could e.g. do `Set rngSrc = .Range("A5").CurrentRegion` for the first (and all the other), and additionally use `Set rngSrc = rngSrc.Resize(rngSrc.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)` for the remaining worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the answer you asked for, but perhaps a PowerQuery would work better here?

If you'd like, you could try the following:

1. Open a **New Workbook**
2. Go to the **Data Ribbon**
3. Select **'Get Data' -> 'From File' -> 'From Folder'**
4. Navigate to the **Folder** housing your files
5. When Prompted select **'Transform Data'**
6. If necessary, set filters to only grab the files you want
7. In the far left **[Content] column**, click the icon with **two down arrows**
8. Select your **table/tab** and click **'OK'**
   (*If more than one table or tab exists within your Workbook, you will be prompted with an option of navigating to the table/tab of your choice, I like to click the checkbox 'Skip files with errors' but that's up to you*)
9. You will now apply a series of steps to get to the data you'd like, in your case and given your example, I would do something along the following lines:
10. **'Remove Rows' -> 'Remove Top Rows' -> Number of Rows = 4**
11. **'Use First Row as Headers'** (*Make sure you removed the top rows first*)
12. **'Filter' on [Column2] to remove nulls**
    (*Assuming Column 2 never has text in rows below your target details, and it always has data matching the last desired row for your data pull*)
13. Now you should have your data, make any other edits you might want with regards to any formatting needs or additional filters you may want performed
14. Select **'Close & Load'**
    (*All files will apply the same logic steps and build the final results into one table*)

Comment: unfortunately I need the solution to be VBA driven as I have to quickly recreate this report over time, I appreciate the suggestion though!